# Extract data for past 7 days (Cannot use current_date function)

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I am currently using Amazon Red Shift and I am trying to extract data for the past 7 days but do not want to use current_date function.

Is there any other alternative way, any suggestions. Thanks..

Comment: what't the reason behind not using `current_date`?

Comment: There is `GETDATE()` or `SYSDATE`, but you should explain why you do not want to use `current_date`.

Comment: I am using this as part of my query to generate dashboards and it throws me an error when the data refreshes for the next day if I use this for filtering dates hence this request..

Comment: so maybe post the error it throws, and let's fix that, instead of being so vague?

Comment: if you do not change the query, the data has not changed  and do not have e.g. current_timestamp then you may be getting a cached result returned by redshift.